# Trouble Deleting in React Native Firebase Firestore

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, expo, delete-file

I am trying to delete an object within a firebase firestore database. This was built in react native expo. When I run the code shown below, the console displays "Doc deleted", however, The object I meant to delete still shows in firebase as well as within my applicaton. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
async function deleteProperty() {
  await firebase.firestore().collection("Properties").get().then((documentSnapshot => {
    documentSnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      if (doc.data().address == route.params.address) {
        firebase.firestore().collection("Properties").doc().delete().then(() => {
          console.log("Doc deleted")
        }).catch((error) => {
          console.error("Error removing document: ", error)
        })
      }
    })
  }))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to pass document id to `doc()` specifically.

```
firebase.firestore().collection("Properties").doc(doc.id).delete().then(() => {
  console.log("Doc deleted")
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error("Error removing document: ", error)
})
```

ref: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data#web-version-8

Comment: Legend, I love you